# Use Ansible S3 module to sync files in EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

Is the below play is the right way to sync files from S3 bucket to instances in EC2?

I am running my play from my mac.

```
    - name: "syncing S3 for Keys"
      hosts: ec2instances
        s3:
          aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
          aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
          bucket: hosts
          mode: get
          object: /data/*
          dest: /etc/data/conf/
```

Answer (score 1):

The ansible S3 module has currently no built-in way to syncronize buckets to disk recursively.

In theory, you could **try** to collect the keys to download with a

```
- name: register keys for syncronization
  s3:     
    mode: list
    bucket: hosts
    object: /data/*
  register: s3_items

- name: sync s3 bucket to disk
  s3:
    mode=get
    bucket=hosts
    object={{ item }}
    dest=/etc/data/conf/
  with_items: s3_bucket_items.s3_keys
```

While I often see this solution, it does not seem to work with current ansible/boto versions, due to a bug with nested S3 'directories' (see [this bug report](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19600) for more information), and the ansible S3 module not creating subdirectories for keys.
I believe it is also possible that you would run into some memory issues using this method when syncing very large buckets.

I also like to add that you most likely do not want to use credentials coded into your playbooks - I suggest you use [IAM EC2 instance profiles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) instead, which are much more secure and comfortable.

A solution that works for me, would be this:

```
- name: Sync directory from S3 to disk
  command: "s3cmd sync -q --no-preserve s3://hosts/{{ item }}/ /etc/data/conf/"
  with_items:
    - data
```